# Difference in the equlibrium of the buckets

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, water, equilibrium

Let there be a bucket of mass on earth resting on floor with water reaching the brim. And now consider another identical bucket with water till brim in outer space with no gravitational influence, and also a 3rd identical bucket with water till brim falling freely near Earth's surface. Here, as we know according to newton's laws, 1'st and 2'nd bucket are in equilibrium as they have no net force acting on them. And the 3rd bucket is accelerating at $g$ in $m/s^2$.

But we tend to say 2'nd and 3'rd buckets are equvalently in identical conditions (saying this because pressure difference pattern in 2'nd and 3'rd buckets is identical).

What is this supposed to be?

Comment: Re, "in outer space with no gravitational influence." There is no such place. Gravity is _everywhere._  For an object orbiting the Earth, an object orbiting the Sun, an object orbiting the galaxy,... it's all the same. Those objects are just as much "freely falling" as is the falling object that is about to crash into the surface of the Earth. There is no difference at all between your 2nd bucket and your 3rd bucket.\*

Comment: \* That is, if we ignore effects due to the third bucket plummeting at tens or hundreds of meters per second through the compressible fluid that we call "air."

Comment: You are confusing Net Force = 0 with no forces acting on a body.

Answer (score 1):

Not all equilibria are equivalent.

In the first case, while the net force on the system is $0$, this does not mean there are no forces at all. For the first bucket on Earth's surface the fluid pressure changes as you go deeper into the bucket due to the weight of the fluid above the point in question.

In the second and third cases there is no fluid pressure gradient as you travel down the bucket. This is because fluid higher up is not pushing down on fluid below it. And this is how the second and third cases are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the second bucket in outer space is in static equilibrium and the third one (that's freely falling) is in dynamic equilibrium. And according to my knowledge, the first one, on the ground, is also in static equilibrium. It would be helpful if you could explain what you meant by "pressure difference pattern in the first and the third buckets is identical".

Comment: my bad, It should have been 2'nd and 3'rd